# How can these two mongodb insert statements differ

Tags: mongodb

I want to insert a nested object in mongodb and the fist code inserts into the database

```
;db.told.insert({ 
name: "admin", 
status: "online",
catalog : [
    {
        "objectid" : ObjectId().str,
        "message" : "sold",
        "status" : "open"
    }]
})
```

but this does not

```
  db.told.insert({
     communicationtype:"sms",
    communicationmessage:[{
                        "objectid" : ObjectId().str,
                        "1" : "House",
                        "2" : "Flat",
                        "3" : "Bungalow",
                        "4" : "Maisonette"
                    }],
    communicationsenton:"a",
    communicationsentby:"b",
    communicationstatus:"sent"
            })
```

Why is the second statement not inserting?

Comment: Do you get any error while doing the second one?

Comment: The console asked me whether i wanted to `Display all 174 possibilities? (y or n)`,am guessing of errors, i said,i was getting back to it on that one.

Comment: Are you aware that you are inserting in two different collections, the one called `now` and another called `told`, so querying `db.now.find()` will give you the documents in the `now` collection, including the one you've just inserted, likewise for `db.told.find()`.

Comment: `told` and `now` are two different collections. So am querying each on its own. The two are not in any way related.Yes i am aware,but still,even if they have identical collection names,two wont insert.

Comment: remove [tabs] when pasting  data into console, I had no issues with that

Comment: It looks like you don't even send your data to mongo but hassle with the shell.

Comment: @profesor79 Yeah,it was all to do with indentation. Thanks. Eiko,thanks for that tip.